# unused keyboard shorcut combinations in VisualStudio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to add few of my own shortcuts, but don't want to overwrite any existing ones.
Do you know some unused key combinations for VS 2010 Express (and optionally VS 2010) ?
Be glad for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I can preview my new keyboard shortcut combination and its possible clashing with existing one by going to keyboard mapping settings in VS in: `Tools \ Options \ Environment \ Keyboard \`, clicking into "Press shortcut keys" input box and pressing my key combination.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add more shortcuts and I needed something better than trial and error, so here is the method I used:

- I installed shortcut exporter: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ce3b73c-2284-4b95-b61d-6de74aa8dfe6
- The generated XML is very simple, so using simple find&replace i extracted keyboard shortcuts separated by "tab" characters,
- I pasted them into spreadsheet and sorted them in a way I liked.
  In this way I can relatively easily see which combinations are not used.